# template static classes across dynamic linked libraries

Tags: c++, class, templates, static

I have a templated class with a static value, like this:

```
  template <class TYPE>
 class A{
  static TYPE value;
 };
```

in the code of a dll I assign the static value:

```
code of  DLL_1

A<float>::value = 2.0;
```

I wish the value to be shared by all the dlls I'm using, i.e. I want that:

```
code of DLL_2

printf("value on DLL_2 %f",A<float>::value);
```

print out  "2.0"

any clues?
thx

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about Windows specifically, you you mention "DLL". As long as you mark you template class/struct as exported, you should be able to set the values in the DLL and use them in another DLL or program.
As far as I understand it, on Windows this requires using `__declspec(dllexport)` when compiling the DLL that sets the values, and `__declspec(dllimport)` when compiling DLLs or programs that use the DLL. For example:
dll.h:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_MY_DLL
# define MY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
# define MY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
template<class TYPE>
struct MY_API A {
    static TYPE value;
};
```

dll.cpp:

```
#include "dll.h"
template<>
A<float>::value = 2.0f;
```

(The `__declspec` part is Windows specific. When using GCC on ELF systems (Linux and the like), you'd use `__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))` to export a the class/struct, and nothing to import it. http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility has some template code where you can set this up more easily.

Comment: This won't work. The specialization is not declared in a header file, so that other translation unit won't know it exists. In other words, One Definition Rule is violated.

Comment: It should work as the symbols will be emitted in the DLL, then when referenced normal symbol lookup should apply. I'm only talking about static class variables here. (I tested with g++ on Ubuntu, the symbols are exported in the library and other libraries or programs can reference them)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually manage instances of your static objects and find and solve duplicates by this way:

myfile.h:

```
// Base class which will make linked list of all static instances
class Base {
protected:
    // make linked list overall template instances
    static Base *first, *last;
    Base *prev, *next;

    Base();
    virtual void set_alias(Base *alias) = 0;
    virtual ~Base();
    static void initialize();
}

// Your template class with template static members
template<typename T>
class MyClass: public Base {
protected:
    T own_data;
    T *aliased_data;

    virtual void set_alias(Base *alias) {
        aliased_data = alias == NULL ? &own_data : ((MyClass<T>*)alias)->aliased_data;
        //if (aliased_data != &own_data) {
        // .... here you can merge data from two clones of template, if need
        //}
    }

public:
    // data accessors
    inline T& data() { return *aliased_data; }
    inline const T& data() const { return *aliased_data; }

    // single instance of class by this you can access staic data field
    static MyClass instance;
}
```

myfile.cpp:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

Base *Base::first = NULL;
Base *Base::last = NULL;

// connect each created instance to static fields
Base::Base(): prev(last), next(NULL) {
    last = (first == NULL ? first : last->next) = this;
}

Base::~Base() {
    (prev == NULL ? first : prev->next) = next;
    (next == NULL ? last  : next->prev) = prev;
}

// find all duplicates and connect it togather
// compare instances by mangled typename
// Note: Base should contain virtual methods so typeid will works proper
Base::initialize() {
    for(Base *i = first; i != NULL; i = i->next)
         for(Base *j = i->next; j != NULL; j = j->next)
              if (std::string( typeid(*i).name() ) == typeid(*j).name())
                  j->set_alias(*i);
}
```

How to use:

```
...
// call initialize when program started and DLL
// with implementation of class Base was loaded
Base::initialize();
...

...
// call initialize again when any other dll which uses MyClass loaded
Base::initialize();
...

...
// now we can use MyClass from any function (from DLL and/or from main program)
MyClass<float>::instance.data() = 10.f;
...

...
std::cout << MyClass<float>::instance.data() << std::endl;
...
```

Note: Anyway you need to make dllexport and any other actions to export and import for functions:

```
Base::Base();
virtual void Base::set_alias(Base *alias) = 0;
virtual Base::~Base();
static void Base::initialize();
```